# Why does this array work with one cell ref but not multiple?

Tags: vba, excel

UPDATE: Sorry still new at this, what I'm looking to achieve is to stop a user saving the worksheet until all "mandatory ranges" are completed across multiple sheets. There's probably a much easier way of doing what I'm trying but I'm still learning, sorry!

The error message I'm getting with the below "does not work" is:

```
Range(man_cell) = <Method 'Range'of object '_Global' failed>
```

---

This is part of a "Submit WorkSheet" macro tied to a command button.

I want to check if all these cells are blank, if any are pop up a MessageBox telling someone they've missed something. If they aren't continue as usual. When I use a single cell reference it works, when I use multiple it does not. I've got named ranges set for all the sheets, but none of them whatsoever would work and a single cell reference works perfectly.

This Works

```
man_cells = Array("'Engagement Form'!$I$6")
```

This does not work

```
man_cells = Array("'Engagement Form'!$I$6", "'Engagement Form'!$I$8'")
```

Code I'm trying to get to work:

```
'Establish if Mandatory Cells have been completed
Dim man_cells As Variant
Dim man_items_count As Integer

man_cells = Array("'Engagement Form'!$I$6'", _
"'Engagement Form'!$I$8", _
"'Engagement Form'!$B$12:$I$12", _
"'Engagement Form'!$B$16:$I$16", _
"'Engagement Form'!$I$18", "'Engagement Form'!$I$28", "'Engagement Form'!$I$30", "'Engagement Form'!$I$32", "'Engagement Form'!$I$36", _
"'Engagement Form'!$I$38", "'Engagement Form'!$I$40", "'Engagement Form'!$I$44", "'Engagement Form'!$I$46", "'Engagement Form'!$I$48", _
"'Engagement Form'!$I$56", "'Engagement Form'!$I$58", "'Engagement Form'!$I$60", "'Engagement Form'!$I$66", "'Engagement Form'!$I$68", _
"'Engagement Form'!$I$70", "'Engagement Form'!$I$72", "'Engagement Form'!$I$74", "'Engagement Form'!$I$78", "'Engagement Form'!$I$80", _
"'Engagement Form'!$I$82", "'Engagement Form'!$I$88", "'Engagement Form'!$I$96", "'Engagement Form'!$I$98", _
"'Engagement Form'!$B$104:$I$104", _
"'Engagement Form'!$I$106", _
"'Engagement Form'!$B$111:$I$111", _
"'Engagement Form'!$B$115:$I$115", _
"'Engagement Form'!$L$6:$Z$120", _
"'Data Protection Crib Sheet'!$B$9:$B$19", _
"'A & A Crib Sheet'!$B$9:$B$44", _
"'Governance Crib Sheet'!$B$9:$B$17")

CellCount = 0
man_items_count = UBound(man_cells) + 1

For Each man_cell In man_cells

    Set rng = Range(man_cell)
    If Len(rng.Text) > 0 Then
        CellCount = CellCount + 1
    End If
Next man_cell

If CellCount <> man_items_count Then

   MsgBox etc
```

Comment: Possibly just a typo, but you have one too many single quotes in `'Engagement Form'!$I$8'`.

Comment: Why don't you just use COUNTA or COUNTBLANK?

Comment: Can you [edit] your post into a proper [mcve] and clarify exactly what "does not work" stands for? Are you getting a specific error by any chance? FWIW an array wants to be iterated with a `For...Next` loop, not with `For Each`. Also `Range(man_cell)` is really `ActiveSheet.Range(man_cell)`, which likely only works if the active sheet is whatever sheet the `man_cell` string is referring to. Looks like the entire approach is off. You might want to `Application.Evaluate(man_cell)` in order to get the `Range` objects, but why not work with ranges in the first place?

Comment: Thanks both, apologies I was tying to be a concise as possible because it's my attempt at throwing together something without ever any specific training. It looks like my entire approach might have just been wrong <sigh> I did try!

Comment: UPDATE: Sorry still new at this, what I'm looking to achieve is to stop a user saving the worksheet until all "mandatory ranges" are completed across multiple sheets.

The error message I'm getting with the below "does not work" is:

    Range(man_cell) = <Method 'Range'of object '_Global' failed>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SJR's first comment is the fix to your question:

> you have one too many single quotes in `'Engagement Form'!$I$8'`

The second comment will simplify your code

---

.

To minimize spelling mistakes I suggest this structure

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CheckRequiredCells1()

    Const EM_1 = "I6,I8,B12:I12,B16:I16,I18,I28,I30,I32,I36,I38,I40,I44,I46,I48,"
    Const EM_2 = "I56,I58,I60,I66,I68,I70,I72,I74,I78,I80,I82,I88,I96,I98,"
    Const EM_3 = "B104:I104,I106,B111:I111,B115:I115,L6:Z120"

    Const EM = EM_1 & EM_2 & EM_3   'Required ranges on Sheet "Engagement Form"
    Const DP = "B9:B19"             'Required ranges on Sheet "Data Protection Crib Sheet"
    Const AA = "B9:B44"             'Required ranges on Sheet "A & A Crib Sheet"
    Const GC = "B9:B17"             'Required ranges on Sheet "Governance Crib Sheet"

    Dim wsEM As Worksheet, wsDP As Worksheet, wsAA As Worksheet, wsGC As Worksheet

    Set wsEM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Engagement Form")     'Reference to the sheet
    Set wsDP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Protection Crib Sheet")
    Set wsAA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A & A Crib Sheet")
    Set wsGC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Governance Crib Sheet")

    Dim rng As Variant, invalid As Long

    For Each rng In Array(wsEM.Range(EM), wsDP.Range(DP), wsAA.Range(AA), wsGC.Range(GC))
        'rng.Cells.Count = total cells in required range for the sheet being processed
        'Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = total cells containing data
        invalid = invalid + (rng.Cells.Count - Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng))
    Next

    If invalid > 0 Then MsgBox "Please fill out all " & invalid & " cells"
End Sub
```

---

.

Edit

As an example, to add a new sheet (called `"Sheet1"`) with its new set of ranges, add lines like this:

```
Const S1 = "A1:A2, B3:B5"       'Required ranges on Sheet1

Dim wsS1 As Worksheet

Set wsS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

and update this line in the `For` loop, to include `wsS1.Range(S1)`:

```
Array(wsEM.Range(EM), wsDP.Range(DP), wsAA.Range(AA), wsGC.Range(GC), wsS1.Range(S1))
```

and the final code becomes:

---

```
Const EM_1 = "I6,I8,B12:I12,B16:I16,I18,I28,I30,I32,I36,I38,I40,I44,I46,I48,"
Const EM_2 = "I56,I58,I60,I66,I68,I70,I72,I74,I78,I80,I82,I88,I96,I98,"
Const EM_3 = "B104:I104,I106,B111:I111,B115:I115,L6:Z120"

Const EM = EM_1 & EM_2 & EM_3   'Required ranges on Sheet "Engagement Form"
Const DP = "B9:B19"             'Required ranges on Sheet "Data Protection Crib Sheet"
Const AA = "B9:B44"             'Required ranges on Sheet "A & A Crib Sheet"
Const GC = "B9:B17"             'Required ranges on Sheet "Governance Crib Sheet"
Const S1 = "A1:A2, B3:B5"       '<--- New sheet, with new equired ranges (on Sheet1)

Dim wsEM As Worksheet, wsDP As Worksheet, wsAA As Worksheet, wsGC As Worksheet
Dim wsS1 As Worksheet           '<--- New sheet

Set wsEM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Engagement Form")     'Reference to the sheet
Set wsDP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Protection Crib Sheet")
Set wsAA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A & A Crib Sheet")
Set wsGC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Governance Crib Sheet")
Set wsS1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<--- New sheet

Dim rng As Variant, invalid As Long

For Each rng In Array(wsEM.Range(EM), wsDP.Range(DP), wsAA.Range(AA), wsGC.Range(GC), _
                      wsS1.Range(S1))
    invalid = invalid + (rng.Cells.Count - Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng))
Next

If invalid > 0 Then MsgBox "Please fill out all " & invalid & " cells"
```

Comment: Not sure if the third is a bug. If I insert `MsgBox rng.Parent.Name` after the `Set rng` line then it returns "Engagement Form" even if that sheet is not active.

Comment: UPDATE: Sorry still new at this, what I'm looking to achieve is to stop a user saving the worksheet until all "mandatory ranges" are completed across multiple sheets.

The error message I'm getting with the below "does not work" is:

    Range(man_cell) = <Method 'Range'of object '_Global' failed>

@paulbica that looks beautiful, I'll try it tomorrow. I'm smoked (moving house madness) can't thank you enough already.

Comment: @paulbica you're a genius, I'm not sure what half of that does but it worked without error straight away. I'm conscious that when I bastardise someone elses work I usually make it pretty ugly. I know you've already done a ton but could I trouble you to remove the mark cells red bit so that it just pops up with the message box and stops executing the macro. I'm hoping I can use conditional formatting to dynamically update the blank cells.

Comment: Sorry internet dropped randomly! That works perfect, PERFECTLY.

I simply cannot thank you enough, I've been trying to get this working for weeks, literally weeks.

What's the most appropriate way to stop executing code IF there's unfilled cells?

There's a section that comes after (that works thankfully) that just saves it to a sharepoint site, if there's incomplete data I don't wait it to save.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Please make sure to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I think that's it accepted @paulbica thank you again!

Comment: I'd have to see how the next section works, but we can change this `Sub()` into a `Function()` that returns `True` or `False`. You can call the function and and stop the next section of code based on the response: If the function returns `True` (as in "there are required cells that are empty") then stop executing the next section and exit the code. If you want you can open a new question, with your next section of code, asking how to stop if this section is incomplete (it's quite simple)

Comment: @paulbica submitted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50053349/excel-vba-stopping-a-section-of-code-correctly

Comment: @paulbica final question (I hope) thank you again, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060145/can-these-individually-referenced-cells-be-converted-into-ranges

Comment: I just logged in now - I added new code to this answer showing you how to add new Sheets with new required ranges - the lines starting with `<--- New sheet`. If you have any issues we'll fix them :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do len text on a range of cells. It will pick up only the len of the first cell in the range. That is one major problem.

The following does a count of cells being worked with versus count of blanks cells. So will test if all cells are completed. There are easier ways to work with ranges. For example, create named ranges and use those.

I use split to extract the worksheet name and the range address so that I can work with those referenced correctly.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    'Establish if Mandatory Cells have been completed
    Dim man_cells As Variant

    man_cells = Array("'Engagement Form'!$I$6'", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$8", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$B$12:$I$12", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$B$16:$I$16", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$18", "'Engagement Form'!$I$28", "'Engagement Form'!$I$30", "'Engagement Form'!$I$32", "'Engagement Form'!$I$36", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$38", "'Engagement Form'!$I$40", "'Engagement Form'!$I$44", "'Engagement Form'!$I$46", "'Engagement Form'!$I$48", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$56", "'Engagement Form'!$I$58", "'Engagement Form'!$I$60", "'Engagement Form'!$I$66", "'Engagement Form'!$I$68", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$70", "'Engagement Form'!$I$72", "'Engagement Form'!$I$74", "'Engagement Form'!$I$78", "'Engagement Form'!$I$80", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$82", "'Engagement Form'!$I$88", "'Engagement Form'!$I$96", "'Engagement Form'!$I$98", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$B$104:$I$104", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$106", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$B$111:$I$111", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$B$115:$I$115", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$L$6:$Z$120", _
                      "'Data Protection Crib Sheet'!$B$9:$B$19", _
                      "'A & A Crib Sheet'!$B$9:$B$44", _
                      "'Governance Crib Sheet'!$B$9:$B$17")

    Dim i As Long, numberBlanks As Long, numberOfCells As Long

    For i = LBound(man_cells) To UBound(man_cells)
        numberBlanks = numberBlanks + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Split(man_cells(i), "'")(1)).Range(Split(Split(man_cells(i), "!")(1), "'")(0)))
        numberOfCells = numberOfCells + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Split(man_cells(i), "'")(1)).Range(Split(Split(man_cells(i), "!")(1), "'")(0)).Cells.Count
    Next i

    If numberBlanks <> numberOfCells Then MsgBox "Etc"
End Sub
```

**Cancelling user save:**

If you want it to involve stop a user saving then you could incorporate as a function call from the Workbook_BeforeSave Event e.g.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
        Cancel As Boolean)

    If CancelSave = True Then Cancel = True
End Sub

Public Function CancelSave() As Boolean

    Dim man_cells As Variant

    man_cells = Array("'Engagement Form'!$I$6'", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$8", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$B$12:$I$12", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$B$16:$I$16", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$18", "'Engagement Form'!$I$28", "'Engagement Form'!$I$30", "'Engagement Form'!$I$32", "'Engagement Form'!$I$36", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$38", "'Engagement Form'!$I$40", "'Engagement Form'!$I$44", "'Engagement Form'!$I$46", "'Engagement Form'!$I$48", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$56", "'Engagement Form'!$I$58", "'Engagement Form'!$I$60", "'Engagement Form'!$I$66", "'Engagement Form'!$I$68", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$70", "'Engagement Form'!$I$72", "'Engagement Form'!$I$74", "'Engagement Form'!$I$78", "'Engagement Form'!$I$80", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$82", "'Engagement Form'!$I$88", "'Engagement Form'!$I$96", "'Engagement Form'!$I$98", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$B$104:$I$104", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$I$106", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$B$111:$I$111", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$B$115:$I$115", _
                      "'Engagement Form'!$L$6:$Z$120", _
                      "'Data Protection Crib Sheet'!$B$9:$B$19", _
                      "'A & A Crib Sheet'!$B$9:$B$44", _
                      "'Governance Crib Sheet'!$B$9:$B$17")

    Dim i As Long, numberBlanks As Long, numberOfCells As Long

    For i = LBound(man_cells) To UBound(man_cells)
        numberBlanks = numberBlanks + Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Split(man_cells(i), "'")(1)).Range(Split(Split(man_cells(i), "!")(1), "'")(0)))
        numberOfCells = numberOfCells + ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Split(man_cells(i), "'")(1)).Range(Split(Split(man_cells(i), "!")(1), "'")(0)).Cells.Count
    Next i

    If numberBlanks > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please complete all mandatory cells"
        CancelSave = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Sorry still new at this, what I'm looking to achieve is to stop a user saving the worksheet until all "mandatory ranges" are completed across multiple sheets.

The error message I'm getting with the below "does not work" is:

    Range(man_cell) = <Method 'Range'of object '_Global' failed>

Comment: You are not getting that specific error with my code as that line doesn't exist. What is happening when you run my code? This can be put in a workbook before save event to cancel a save operation if, for example, numberBlanks > 0.

Comment: I have included an example cancel user save.