# Can these individually referenced cells be converted into ranges?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a little unsure how and if I can use named ranges with the below rather than cells.

The cells on this worksheet are all over the place and there's more sheets to add at a later date so working with named ranges would make my life an awful lot easier.

I'm just not sure if the Const property will allow me to use a named range and if so how.

```
'Establish if Mandatory Cells have been completed
Const EM_1 = "I6,I8,B12:I12,B16:I16,I18,I28,I30,I32,I36,I38,I40,I44,I46,I48,"
Const EM_2 = "I56,I58,I60,I66,I68,I70,I72,I74,I78,I80,I82,I88,I96,I98,"
Const EM_3 = "B104:I104,I106,B111:I111,B115:I115,L6:Z120"

Const EM = EM_1 & EM_2 & EM_3   'Required ranges on Sheet "Engagement Form"
Const DP = "B9:B19"             'Required ranges on Sheet "Data Protection Crib Sheet"
Const AA = "B9:B44"             'Required ranges on Sheet "A & A Crib Sheet"
Const GC = "B9:B17"             'Required ranges on Sheet "Governance Crib Sheet"

Dim wsEM As Worksheet, wsDP As Worksheet, wsAA As Worksheet, wsGC As Worksheet

Set wsEM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Engagement Form")     'Reference to the sheet
Set wsDP = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Protection Crib Sheet")
Set wsAA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A & A Crib Sheet")
Set wsGC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Governance Crib Sheet")

Dim rng As Variant, invalid As Long

For Each rng In Array(wsEM.Range(EM), wsDP.Range(DP), wsAA.Range(AA), wsGC.Range(GC))
    'rng.Cells.Count = total cells in required range for the sheet being processed
    'Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = total cells containing data
    invalid = invalid + (rng.Cells.Count - Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng))
Next

If invalid > 0 Then
MsgBox "Something's missing. Please check and try again. There are " & _
                  invalid & " incomplete fields.", vbOKOnly
Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Check [Application.Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-union-method-excel). With this, you can create a single range composed of different ranges of data, and then checl every cell in this *final big range*

Comment: Thanks @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns but I'm looking to see about converting cells to ranges rather than ranges to larger range.

Comment: Well, a cell is just the same as a range with width=1 and height=1 so there is nothing to convert. It's just another way to access. `Cells(1, 1)` also returns a range. I don't understand your question, please clarify.

Comment: Just for clarification, does your code throw any error? `Const EM = EM_1 & EM_2 & EM_3` concatenates addresses without delimiter. Do you want to make range a constant or what?.. Question is unclear.

Comment: @AntiDrondert there are `,` at the end of `EM_1` and `EM_2` so I see delimiters.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Overlooked it. As far as I can understand, OP wants to use range constants and asks if it is possible.

Comment: Hi guys, the above code works perfectly as is. @AntiDrondert has it, I just want to use constant ranges if possible and I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot make a constant a range. A constant must be of type `Byte`, `Boolean`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Currency`, `Single`, `Double`, `Decimal` (not currently supported), `Date`, `String`, or `Variant`.

See the documentation: [Const Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/const-statement).

Comment: Thanks PEH, this is the sort of thing I was looking for before I go wading in messing with stuff I don't fully understand.